# how to solve this error "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am trying to update my project, but he is giving this error when running the `composer update` Does anybody know how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `jenssegers/mongodb` that is not compatible with `Laravel7`

You need to use `Laravel6` to resolve this error

```
Laravel version Compatibility
Laravel Package
4.2.x   2.0.x
5.0.x   2.1.x
5.1.x   2.2.x or 3.0.x
5.2.x   2.3.x or 3.0.x
5.3.x   3.1.x or 3.2.x
5.4.x   3.2.x
5.5.x   3.3.x
5.6.x   3.4.x
5.7.x   3.4.x
5.8.x   3.5.x
6.x 3.6.x
```

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb